# Example of NOT a function?

Tags: functions

Thinking of things I can graph.
Age vs. height, Salary, # of friends, etc
Time vs. stock price

Everything is a function!

Can anyone think of a graph that would fail the Vert. line test
and is not a function?

Not some equation of a circle, mind you
but an actual graph of something in life.

Comment: https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/MagParticle/Physics/HysteresisLoop.htm

Comment: Just rotate an existing one - e.g. stock price vs. time. This feels unnatural, but that's because of convention: we talk about "graphing $A$ against $B$" *precisely when* one is a function of the other.

Comment: Oh, we've just been trained to think in terms of functions.  Try analyzing ugly data like "parents' education" vs "lifetime income".   No function there, but you can see where there might be function-like questions.

Comment: [Scatter Graphs](https://www.google.com/search?q=scatter+graphs&tbm=isch)

Comment: Hmm.  Scatter plots typically are used to display data about different people.  (Age vs. Salary, for example).   So, how about an example of a scatter plot about a single person, where he has multiple values for a given age, for example  (Age vs ____________)

Comment: Yea, but the rotated stock/time graph is non-sensical.  I want an actual data that happens to not be a function.

Comment: Does kronecker delta count ? It has Some intresting properties that you can not expect from “ normal functions “. It is called a “ distribution or pseudofunction “ . In particular integrals involving the kronecker delta in the integrand can be counterintuitive or surprising.

Comment: I don't understand a single word you've just said.  So, no, it does not count.